# Classic ASP form to perl and vice-versa

Tags: asp.net, perl, asp-classic

I have a sample.asp form page written as follows:

```html
<form method="POST" action="index.asp">
    <p>Switch IP:<input type="test" name="SwitchIP"></p>
    <p>Login: <input type="test" name="Login"></p>
    <p>Password:<input type="password" name="Password"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"><p>
</form>
```

It takes up three input variables ip, login and password by using the submit button.

I have a perl script which is as follows:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Net::Telnet::Cisco;

my $SwitchIP = '192.168.10.1';

my $session = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(Host => $host, -Prompt=>'/(?m:^[\w.&-]+\s?(?:\  (config[^\)]*\))?\s?[\$#>]\s?(?:\(enable\))?\s*$)/');

$session->login(Name => 'admin',Password => 'password');
$session->cmd('terminal length 0');
my @ver = $session->cmd('show mac-address-table dynamic');
print @ver;
$session->close();
```

This script runs on a cisco switch and prints out the 'show mac-address-table dynamic' command. I would like to know how to combine this 2 scripts such that data from ASP form is fed to the perl script and the @ver output is printed out back on the screen. 
I am running this using Apache::ASP on a linux server.
Please correct me if anything is not correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1, make it so that your perl script can accept parameters.  Might want to add some error checking to this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Net::Telnet::Cisco;

my ($host, $name, $password) = @ARGV;

my $session = Net::Telnet::Cisco->new(Host => $host, -Prompt=>'/(?m:^[\w.&-]+\s?(?:\  (config[^\)]*\))?\s?[\$#>]\s?(?:\(enable\))?\s*$)/');

$session->login(Name => $name,Password => $password);
$session->cmd('terminal length 0');
my @ver = $session->cmd('show mac-address-table dynamic');
print @ver;
$session->close();
```

Step 2, Test to ensure this works from the command line:

```
perl yourscript.pl 192.168.10.1 admin password
```

Step 3, Make it so that ASP form can call the perl script upon a POST.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am able to run it from the command line. But how can I integrate ASP and perl. Which commands to use to call perl script from ASP and give them the '@ARGV' (In your case) from ASP and print the '@ver' (in the above script) to the ASP page. Thanks.

Comment: @deep, to call the perl script from ASP, set the action attribute of the form equal to the filename of the perl script: `<form method='post' action='yourscript.pl'>` (I *think* that'll work from the asp end; no clue what perl will do with it, though.) To send the @ver value back to asp, you could do a redirect from the perl script to your asp page, with the value added to the querystring: `youraspfile.asp?Ver=[insert @ver here]`.